# How to prove that $\lim _{\left(x,\:y\right)\to \left(1,\:0\right)}\log _x\left(x+y\right)$ doesn't exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I know that $$\lim _{\left(x,\:y\right)\to \left(1,\:0\right)}\log _x\left(x+y\right)$$ does not exist, but could you help me to prove that? I've tried a lot, but I have no idea how to do it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Professor gave us hint that conversion to $\frac{\log _e\left(x+y\right)}{\log _e\left(x\right)}$ may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's ignore the fact that the function is undefined for $x=1$ (although, depending on the definition in your book, this just might be the expected explanation). So let's say that the limit is considered as $(x,y)\to(1,0)$ within the domain of the function.

To simplify the solution a little bit, let's change the first variable via $x=1+x'$, so that $x'\to0$ as $x\to1$. Then the given limit can be rewritten as
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,0)}\log_x(x+y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,0)}\frac{\ln(x+y)}{\ln(x)}=\lim_{(x',y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\ln(1+x'+y)}{\ln(1+x')}.$$

Now we can find different paths that give different values of the limit. For example, consider paths $y=kx'$ for different constant values of $k$. Then
$$\lim_{(x',y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\ln(1+x'+y)}{\ln(1+x')}=\lim_{x'\to0}\frac{\ln(1+(1+k)x')}{\ln(1+x')},$$
and you can find this limit using L'Hôpital's Rule or Taylor Series.

Comment: That's great idea, thanks! I considered $\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)$, so $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{ln\left(\frac{1}{n}+1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{ln\left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)}\right)=2$ and $\left(\frac{1}{n},0\right)$: $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{ln\left(\frac{1}{n}+1+0\right)}{ln\left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)}\right)=1$. Because these limits are different, we can say that $\lim _{\left(x,y\right)\to \left(1,0\right)}\log _x\left(x+y\right)$ doesn't exist.